# WP WooCommerce page product quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I create single page for product. Hopw I can add quantity option before button "add to card"?

[image]

```
    <ul class="products-list">
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'product-category', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

                <li class="product">    
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
                        <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?></a>
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>   
                        <p class="shortdescription"><?php echo $product->get_short_description();?></p>

//QUNATITY

                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
                </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

I try with form code, and it working. But I want to find another way and add to first code. This is code for form.

```
<form class="cart" action="http://localhost/product/safelogic-basic/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="quantity buttons_added clearfix">
    <div class="quantity_controll_con">
        <input type="button" class="quantity_controll minus" value="-">
        <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*"
            inputmode="numeric">
        <input type="button" class="quantity_controll plus" value="+">
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="6995" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to this WooCommerce function

```
woocommerce_quantity_input();
```

OR If you want to show both the Qty textbox and addtocart button, there is an another WooCommerce function.Check as below.

```
do_action('woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart');
```

Comment: Thanks, I replace `woocomerce_template_loop_add_to_card` with `woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart` and it's working

Comment: Happy to help.. :)